# Access managed bean from separate web application on same server?

Tags: jsf, servlets, javabeans

I have two applications. The first called app1 is a JSF 1.2 application. The second called app2 is a basic Servlet application. Is it possible to access a specific managed session bean in app1 from app2? Both are deployed on the same server.

Thanks Tom

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion would be to convert your app1 beans into EJB3 beans and then access them from app2 using the "Local" interfaces (since both app1 and app2 are on the same server)

The changes are minimal (some annotations and interfaces). Of course your applicaation server needs to be EJB3 compliant.